# CakePHP 3, Very Basic Save Not Working

Tags: cakephp-3.0

For some reason the automated conversion of `$this->request->data` to an entity is not working.  I created a very basic save in order to test it.

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('VendorName/Users.Users');
$this->request->data = ['username' => 'someting', 'password' => 'somethingelse'];
$user = $users->newEntity($this->request->data);
if ($users->save($user)) { }
```

This is the SQL that that produces::

```
INSERT INTO users (created, modified, id) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2)
```

I've tried making `$this->request->data` as a function, eg. `$this->request->data()`

I've tried explicitly adding the entity value. Eg. `$user->username = 'someting';` and it works when I do this. But of course, I don't want to explicitly state every single field in every single save function, so why isn't `$this->request->data` converting automatically?

This is the what `$user` looks like

```
object(VendorName\Users\Model\Entity\User) {

    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'VendorName/Users.Users'

}
```

Comment: What does your `User` entity look like?

Comment: editing the question to add that info (so it can be formatted right)

Comment: Do you have validation rules in the `UsersTable`? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've specified that no fields in the Entity are allowed to be mass assigned (See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment), by having `protected $_accessible = [];` in your Entity class (`VendorName\Users\Model\Entity\User`).

It sounds like you want all properties to be mass assignable, so what you probably want is `protected $_accessible = ['*' => true];`.

Just note that this is dangerous as it can allow anybody to alter their form slightly and then modify any other entity. A better setting is `protected $_accessible = ['id' => false, '*' => true];`